# Grails5 upgrade - hibernate now returning a hibernate proxy instead of actual object - why?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I am in the process of debugging issues of upgrading our app to Grails 5 from 3. This little bit of code was throwing an error that it could not be converted when it should have been able to.

```
 if (item.product.instanceOf(Tissue)) {
        Tissue product = (Tissue) item.product
 }
```

after reading other post i fixed the error by  `Hibernate.unproxy(item.product)` and it works as expected. What changed during the upgrade to cause me to have to do this? Is there some configuration I can apply to revert the behavior back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this was a design choice by the Grails team - https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/issues/1468

> We've reviewed this issue and have determined that GORM is behaving as
> expected in this situation.
>
> One of the changes in GORM for Hibernate 7, is that it no longer
> creates custom proxy factories. It also no longer automatically
> unwraps Hibernate proxies. This change makes the behavior in GORM more
> consistent with standard Hibernate.
>
> While the change was documented in the GORM for Hibernate Upgrade
> Notes we did find that our documentation needed to be updated
> regarding this change including guidance for situations where
> inheritance is involved such as the example in this issue.
>
> The updated documentation will be published with the next release of
> GORM.